# How to configure all fields in a list to be searchable?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience

On SharePoint Online, I create a list with multiple fields, including `Title` and `Description`. I am quite impressive that the `Title` become almost immediately searchable thru the search box at the top (screen below). However the description field is not searchable.

I believe I am using a modern view page. If the searchbox is not configurable, could I create a search for this list only (in classic view, all list come with a search box).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**By design, the Modern SharePoint Lists don't support the "Find an item" search box.** Only when you switch to the Classic mode will the "**Find an item**" search box appear.

So you cannot create a search box for the SharePoint List in Modern mode.

If you need to search items based on the value of the Description column, you should configure the **Search Schema** of the site collection.

[image]

[image]

Thanks, have a nice day!

=============================== **Updated Answer** =============================

You do not need to add a Search Box control, you can directly search items in the "Find an item" Search Box based on the value of the Description column.

[image: Find an item]

Have a lucky day!

Comment: after configure search schema, I can search description column in "Find an item"? Or I need to add a search box control myself?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the response under my original Answer, hope this helps you.

Comment: So I need to switch back to classic view? Could I search description in modern view?

Comment: You don’t need to consider whether you need to switch views, whether it’s classic mode or modern mode, you can easily search items based on the Description column.